# How to enable Angular PWA service worker?

Tags: angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Within an Angular project the following commands were run using the command line:

```
ng add @angular/pwa  
ng build --prod
```

The output in the /dist folder was published as a static website.
https://azureadb2ctesting1.z9.web.core.windows.net/

When running the URL through [PWABuilder](https://www.pwabuilder.com/), the manifest is detected, but not the service worker. Also when changing the networking in Chrome devtools to `offline`, the page does not load normally, but displays "There is no Internet connection" instead.

Also notice the following error in the console:

> main.cb0300ed077227f6fc7f.js:1 Service worker registration failed with: DOMException: Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('https://azureadb2ctesting1.z9.web.core.windows.net/') with script ('https://azureadb2ctesting1.z9.web.core.windows.net/ngsw-worker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/plain').

How can the service worker be enabled for this Angular PWA?

Answer (score 0):

In angular.json you should have : `"serviceWorker": true`

In your application root module you should have the following line in the import :

```
ServiceWorkerModule.register('/ngsw-worker.js', { enabled: environment.production })
```

Comment: Those are both there. Looks like they were automatically generated when running the command line installation.

Comment: But that issue is not output to the console in dev tools. There is another error output about unsupported MIME type ('text/plain'). See the developer console in the example link, also added the error into the question above.

Comment: It looks like a problem with hosting and serving rather than a problem with Angular. Your link is not valid, how did you build your project and how do you serve it ?

Comment: https://azureadb2ctesting1.z9.web.core.windows.net/ is the link to the example. Built using the command `ng build --prod`. Files moved into Azure Storage container configured as a static website.

Comment: Are you sure all your url are set to use https ?

Comment: Yes, the website uses HTTPS.

Comment: If you run an audit in chrome dev tools you can have further info about service worker problems. Also what is your version of angular ? Do you have all angular dependencies that match the same version number ?

Comment: I changed the MIME type to `application/javascript`. It is working now.